# SQL - How can I JOIN two tables and SUM a column based on IDs between them?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have two tables. One table is with master data

**Table tbl1:**

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| ID          | Name       | Total      | 
+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1           | a          | 10         |
| 2           | b          | 5          |
| 3           | c          | 4          |
| 4           | a          | 4          |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Second table `tbl2` contains child data. The key between tables is ID

**Table tbl2:**

```
+-------------+------------+
|id           | qty        | 
+-------------+------------+
| 1           | 4          |              
| 1           | 3          |                
| 1           | 1          |                
| 3           | 1          |                
| 3           | 3          |                
+-------------+------------+
```

I need to get output like this:

**Output:**

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| name        | sum_tot    | sum_qty    | 
+-------------+------------+------------+
| a           | 14         | 8          |
| b           | 5          | 0          |
| c           | 4          | 4          |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

I had tried with this:

```
select tbl1.name, SUM(tbl1.total), SUM(tbl2.qty)
from tbl1
left join tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
GROUP by tbl1.name
```

The output that I get is:

**Output:**

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| name        | sum_tot    | sum_qty    | 
+-------------+------------+------------+
| a           | 34         | 8          |
| b           | 5          |null        |
| c           | 8          | 4          |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Which is not correct.

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646b08/3):

[image]

The summary from first table is not in relation with second table. It seems that somehow query runs three times.

Comment: explain the logic how `a` become 14?

Comment: a appears twice in table 1, once with a value of 10, once with a value of 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply have a correlated sub-query that calculates the tbl2 sum:

```
select tbl1.name, 
       SUM(tbl1.total), 
       SUM(COALESCE((select SUM(tbl2.qty) 
                     from tbl2
                     where tbl1.id = tbl2.id), 0)) as qty_tot
from tbl1
GROUP by tbl1.name
```

Comment: Hm... this works fine but there is one problem. See this: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d7b75/1). For name a total sum_tot is 19 which is correct but sum_qty should 21 not 8. Id 1, 4 and 8 are in tbl2 and they are related to name a.

Comment: Check back in a minute! Done.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT A.name, SUM(A.total) as sum_tot, COALESCE(B.sum_qty, 0) as sum_qty
FROM tbl1 A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(qty) as sum_qty
    FROM tbl2
    GROUP BY id
) B ON B.id = A.id
GROUP BY A.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.name, SUM(tbl1.total), SUM(COALESCE(tbl2.qty, 0))
from tbl1
left join tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
GROUP by tbl1.name
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this give the same result as mine. There should be for name sum of total = 14 but the sum for child items in tbl2 related to id 1 is 8.

Comment: this replaces NULL with 0. Which is half of the solution for the problem. But it still shows 8 for value C on table 1, instead of 4.